# What is the difference between ∀ and Π in the Calculus of Constructions?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-types, calculus-of-constructions

As I've learned, the Calculus of Constructions has only two binders - $\lambda$ and $\Pi$. Morte, for example, has $\forall$ as a mere alias of $\Pi$. Yet, on the paper [Self Types for Dependently Typed Lambda Encodings](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~astump/papers/fu-stump-rta-tlca-14.pdf), there are types such as:

$$\begin{gather}
  \mathrm{Nat} := \forall X. (X \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X \rightarrow X \\
  \mathrm{It} : \forall X. \Pi x : \mathrm{Nat}. (X \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X \rightarrow X \\
  \mathrm{Ind} : \forall P : \mathrm{Nat} \rightarrow \mathord{\ast}. \; \Pi x:\mathrm{Nat}. \; (\Pi y:\mathrm{Nat}. (P \, y \rightarrow P (S \, y))) \rightarrow P \, \bar 0 \rightarrow P \, x
\end{gather}$$

Notice that the paper uses both $\forall$ and $\Pi$. Moreover, $\forall$ is used both with the syntax $\forall a : b \rightarrow c$ and $\forall a . b$. I can't parse those expressions. What is the difference between $\forall$ and $\Pi$, and how would you express those types on Morte?

Comment: Section 3 of the paper gives the syntax and semantics of the language - this should answer the question as to how these two constructs differ. Perhaps you could make this question less open-ended by asking a specific question about the aforementioned semantics. It seems to me like Forall ranges over kinds only, whereas Pi can range over types as well as kinds (section 3.1).

Comment: `∀` is from [The Implicit Calculus of Constructions](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~miquel/publis/tlca01.pdf). `∀P :Nat→∗.` should be parsed as `∀(P :Nat→∗).` (although it seems a bit strange to me to make `P` implicit in this case). Implicit arguments are convenient, but you can express everything with just `Π` — you'll just need a bit more lambdas and applications.

Comment: Based on the examples you give, $\forall$ quantifies over types and $\Pi$ quantifies over values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had only a quick and cursory look at the paper — so take this with great care.

It appears that $\Pi X$ is used to express dependent products as in the calculus of constructions. Instead, $\forall X$ looks more like polymorphic types in ML.

The main difference is that, if $t : \Pi x. P(x)$ then $t T : P(T)$, while if $t : \forall x. P(x)$ then $t : P(T)$. Note that the former requires an additional argument, the second does not: the polytype gets instantiated automatically. Rules $\mathit{App}$ and $\mathit{Inst}$ at page 7 cause this difference.

Of course, this also means that introducing $\Pi$ requires a lambda, while introducing $\forall$ does not.

There also is some type / kind distinction related to this, but I can't comment on that precisely.

Comment: Perhaps the forall is for parameters and the pi for indices?

Comment: Wait so there are many different versions of CoC itself?

Comment: @Viclib This paper proposes its own calculus, which differs from CoC, despite borrowing many ideas from it.